# Ubuntu 16.04 boot into busybox

Tags: 16.04, dual-boot, windows-10, initramfs, busybox

I use a laptop which dual boot with Windows 10.

When I switch on my laptop it will boots into busybox.

When I reboot by typing reboot in busybox it will boot correctly into Ubuntu.

I have search for similar problems, and tried a couple of suggestions including running fsck on my drive, but could not find any remedy as yet.

Your help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

you can try reinstalling Ubuntu using a USB drive, and make sure you configure your bootloader properly this time.